# Why cant I run my application with a default file like that of notepad?

Tags: autoit

Why cant I run my application with a default file like that of Notepad ? 
AutoIt sample code below :

```
 Example()

 Func Example()
        ; Run Notepad
        Run("Notepad.exe " & "C:\Users\judith_francis\Desktop\dd.txt")

        Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\abc.exe" & "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test_image.tif")

 EndFunc
```

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: I am not able to run this line Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\abc.exe" & "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test_image.tif")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\abc.exe" & "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test_image.tif")
```

Runs the command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\abc.exeC:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test_image.tif
```

Which Windows will interpret as

```
C:\Program
```

Try instead

```
  Run('"C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\abc.exe" ' & '"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test_image.tif"')
```

Which adds the necessary space & quotes & will be executed as

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\abc.exe" "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test_image.tif"
```